# Laptop display has green and pink lines

Tags: windows, laptop, display

My laptop's display is acting weird. Whenever I login into my account, display shows green and pink lines without flickering for a minute or two and then it goes back to normal display.

It only happens when I lock my account and sign in. I don't think it is a hardware problem because of this.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Quick test. Take a screenshot. Check once it's stopped being weird [or on another computer] If it's not on the screenshot, it's hardware. If it is on it, it's software.

Comment: You're right it is not on the screenshot so i guess hardware it is. But why does it do this when I log out and again log into my account? It should be like this all the time.

Comment: Really not sure. Might be heat-affected, or lid-related… likely to need a repair shop to accurately diagnose.